Regex to remove start and ending parentheses inside non nested tag
I faced a problem trying to extract, through Regex, from the following:
<mrow>(<mn>1000001</mn>)</mrow
the inner <mn>1000001</mn>.
I have resolved it with a work around, but wonder if the need of a workaround has been my lack of expertise (most probably) or a bug.
Done I need the <mrow>...</mrow> not to be nested, as they may be, the Regex pattern was:
<mrow[^\>]*>\(?((?:(?!<mrow>[^\>]*>|<\/mrow>).)*)\)?<\/mrow>

where (?:(?!<mrow>[^\>]*>|<\/mrow>).)* is to assure the most inner tag: not nested. The \(? and \)? in the pattern are there because tags <mrow>... </mrow> may or may not have parentheses next to them <mrow>(...)</mrow>.
So, I was expecting that Regex would give me for
 s = "<mrow>(<mn>1000001</mn>)</mrow>"

 Dim mc2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(s, "<mrow[^\>]*>\(?((?:(?!<mrow>[^\>]*>|<\/mrow>).)*)\)?<\/mrow>")
  For Each m2 as Match In mc2
    s = s.Replace(m2.Value, m2.Groups(1).Value)
  Next


as result, s = "<mn>1000001</mn>"; but, and here comes the problem, s is:
"<mn>1000001</mn>)"
I ask myself and you, of course, to explain, please, where does the last character ) in s come from ?
Edit:
My workaround was:
    s = "<mrow>(<mn>1000001</mn>)</mrow>"
    Dim mc2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(s, "<mrow[^\>]*>(\(?(?:(?!<mrow>[^\>]*>|<\/mrow>).)*\)?)<\/mrow>")
    For Each m In mc2
        If Regex.Matches(m.Groups(1).Value, "<").Count = 2 Then
            Dim s1 As String = Regex.Replace(m.Groups(1).Value, "^\(|\)$", "")
            s = s.Replace(m.Value, s1)
        End If
    Next
    Trace.WriteLine(s) ' <mn>1000001</mn>

This is, my need is to remove <mrow> and </mrow> and, if next to it and present, ( and ). But only when there is maximum one tag inside: in the case here <mn>1000001</mn>.
Edit (B)
I finally found what was happening.
Pattern
<mrow[^\>]*>\(?((?:(?!<mrow>[^\>]>|<\/mrow>).)*)\)?<\/mrow> 

has one character '>' left over. Instead, it should be:
<mrow[^\>]*>\(?((?:(?!<mrow[^\>]>|<\/mrow>).)*)\)?<\/mrow> 

Edit (C)
This is really confusing: the problem persists! At least, this is what I found. For the code:
Sub Main()
    Dim s As String = "<msub><mi>y</mi><mrow>(<mi>n</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn>)</mrow></msub><mo>=</mo><msub><mi>y</mi><mrow>(<mi>n</mi><mo>-</mo><mn>1</mn>)</mrow></msub><mo>*</mo><msup><mrow>(<msub><mi>y</mi><mi>n</mi></msub>)</mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></msup>"
    Console.WriteLine(s)
    Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(s, _
"<mrow>(\(?((?:(?!<mrow>|<\/mrow>).)*)\)?)<\/mrow>")
    For i As Int32 = 0 To mc.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("----- " + i.ToString + " ------")
        Console.WriteLine("Group 1: " + mc(i).Groups(1).Value)
        Console.WriteLine("Group 2: " + mc(i).Groups(2).Value)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

the output is:


For your example data, you could prevent crossing a form of <mrow> without using an alternation (?!</?mrow\b[^>]*>
While this works for you example data, this is not fool proof and there are no guarantees here as the . in the regex that matches any character can still match < and >
The suggestion here is to make it non greedy, and optionally match the leading opening and the trailing closing parenthesis.
<mrow[^>]*>\(?((?:(?!</?mrow\b[^>]*>).)*?)\)?</mrow>

See a regex demo

Thanks for your suggestion I'll keep it in mind. But what makes me wonder and I ask is where does the left over ')' come from?

As you may see in 'Edit (C)', term has been reduced to '' and still right parenthesis is left over.

@XavierJunqué because the pattern is greedy, the dot matches any character and the parenthesis is optional

If there would really only be at most one (<mn>1000001</mn>) term in the string, you could do a regex replacement on ^.*\(|\).*$:
string s = "<mrow>(<mn>1000001</mn>)</mrow";
string output = Regex.Replace(s, @"^.*\(|\).*$", "");
Console.WriteLine(output);  // <mn>1000001</mn>


Yes, there may be more than one term and parentheses may or may not be in the string.
